# How to detect ftp file name is a directory?

Tags: java, ftp, directory

In Java I'm trying to delete a ftp directory. But if it's not empty, I need to delete all files and sub-dirs in it, by calling `files[]=ftp.dir()`. I can get a list from the dir, but how can I tell if one of the items in the list is a file or sub-dir ? Is there a `files[i].IsDirectory` method in ftp command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [apache FTP Client](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for this. In that library there is a method called [listFiles()](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles%28java.lang.String%29) that returns an array of [FTPFile](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html). For each `FTPFile` you can call the [getType()](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#getType%28%29) method to determine the [type code constant](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#line.35) for a directory or a file. Quote from the java docs of getType():-

```
public int getType()

    Return the type of the file (one of the _TYPE constants), e.g., if it is a directory, a regular file, or a symbolic link.

    Returns:
        The type of the file.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this : http://www.example-code.com/java/ftp_deleteTree.asp